Incorrect regular expression in Qt
I checked this regular expression here but in Qt its don't work and return false. I guess its my mistake in rx but how can I change this regular expression so it will return true when I input correct sum (examples of input: 43+3; 32-5; -12-32; -43+53) also its impossible to input incorrect sum (example of input: -12+-+23; -34---3; +43+1-3)
and then write in console correct index with position of + or - between two numbers.
//ui->labelAnswer->text() = "12+3"
 static QRegularExpression rx("\\b[+-]"); //here's update
 QRegularExpressionMatch match = rx.match(ui->labelAnswer->text());
 qDebug() << match.hasMatch() << '\n';
 if(match.hasMatch())
{
    int index = match.lastCapturedIndex();
    qDebug() << index << '\n';
}


UPDATE:
I change ("\b[+-]") on ("\\b[+-]") and it returns true, but index is incorrect and equals 0

Why is "\b" in a regular expression?  The '\b' is the backspace character and usually not in strings, but sent to output streams.

The match is "+", match.lastCapturedIndex() is 0 - this is correct.

"\b" is a BACKSPACE. "\\b" is a combination of two chars, \ and b, and it is a word boundary. The "update" has nothing to do with your actual original question, of course it shows 0 since your regex has no capturing groups and the group that matched the - was Group with Index 0. See the docs.

Please note that '-' character has a special meaning of a range bound separator when used within a [] clause in a regular expression, for instance, "[0-9]" matches any decimal digit. Therefore, the element [+-] is incorrect. To avoid that a special treatment when '-' is intended to be merely a character of choice, one may place it to the very first position after the opening bracket. So, you may want to spell your regexp as "\\b[-+]".
